# Trying to get Scrapy to work with Pycharm in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, pycharm

I am migrating to Windows, and am desiring to get Scrapy to work with Pycharm.  What I have tried adding:

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
```

As well as changing - `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py.  It did not like this.`

My output looks like this-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpjnn.jpg

I have also tried:

```
from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider".split())
```

As well as setting the "script" parameter to `/path_to_project_env/env/bin/scrapy`

I get:
"

```
*] beginning main thread
Scrapy 1.4.0 - no active project
```

Unknown command: crawl

Use "scrapy" to see available commands

Process finished with exit code 2
" 
Though nothing is executed, no website is scraped.

I can run scrapy fine in CMD and in Linux.

It does not want to recognise Scrapy with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would install scrapy with anaconda, which I find very convenient (even under Windows): `conda install scrapy`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I have already installed through Conda + Pip.   I get pydev debugger: process 7392 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.4343.24).  If I run anything it just finishes with exist code.  I can type: Write to C:/dwadaw/dawd/dwada/wdaw and it completely ignores what I am writing but finishes successfully